# Mac OS X View Swapping

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I am developing an application which has an image and some buttons whose position remain unchanged during the entire flow. So I subclassed the NSViewController. This is the main view of my application with the fixed buttons and image. I add an NSBox item into which various subviews will be displayed and swapped in/out. How do I display the custom view on button click event in this box? I tried the following code:

```
    intro = [[Introduction alloc] initWithNibName:@"Introduction" bundle:nil];
    [intro setNextResponder:[self nextResponder]];
    [self setNextResponder:intro];            
    [box setContentView:[intro view]];
```

But I get the following error:
-[NSViewController loadView] loaded the "Introduction" nib but no view was set.

The File's Owner is set to Introduction class.

Answer (score 11):

I get this error when I change the class of my File's Owner in IB.

When I get this error, I can generally fix it by remaking the connection between File's Owner and the view. Control-drag from the File's owner to your View (in IB) and select view from the pop-up menu.

Comment: This is the right answer, but I think it needs a little clarification. Basically nevan is saying that you need to connect the view outlet on your view controller to the view in Interface Builder

Comment: I control-drag the File's Owner, but why I cannot get the popup menu (nothing happened)